# Convert final two digits to a percent value over 60. (e.g., 15 / 60 => .25 etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have given numbers like these:

> 0915
>   0930
>   0945
>   1000
>   0015

They should be rounded and look like this:

> 0900 => 9 
>   0915 => 9.25
>   0930 => 9.5
>   0945 => 9.75
>   1000 => 10
>   0015 => 0.25

I tried a lot of functions like round and ceil but i cant get it working. It is for a calendar, the given numbers are the times where the meetings start like '09:45'.

Comment: Are you sure they are **numbers** really? Where do they come from? if from user input, they are obviously **text**, not numbers.

Comment: They come from data-attributes @hindmost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n.substr(0,2)*1 + n.substr(2,2)/60
```

will give you the expected result

where `n` is a string representing time in the format **HHmm** where **HH** is the hour, **mm** minutes as in the data you posted as example. Both value must be two digits numbers forming a 4 digits string.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the minutes by division with 60.

```js
var data = ['0915', '0930', '0945', '1000', '0015'],
    result = data.map(function (a) {
        return +a.slice(0, 2) + a.slice(2, 4) / 60;
    });

console.log(result);
```